# Flex default rule

Tags: c, tokenize, lex, flex-lexer

How do I customize the default action for flex. I found something like <*> but when I run it it says "flex scanner jammed"? Also the . rule only adds a rule so it does not work either. What I want is

```
comment               "/*"[^"*/"]*"*/"

%%
{comment}             return 1;
{default}             return 0; 
<<EOF>>               return -1;
```

Is it possible to change the behavior of matching longest to match first? If so I would do something like this

```
default               (.|\n)*
```

but because this almost always gives a longer match it will hide the comment rule.

EDIT

I found the {-} operator in the manual, however this example straight from the manual gives me "unrecogized rule":

[a-c]{-}[b-z]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The flex default rule matches a single character and prints it on standard output. If you don't want that action, write an explicit rule which matches a single character and does something else.

The pattern `(.|\n)*` matches the entire input file as a single token, so that is a very bad idea. You're thinking that the default should be a long match, but in fact you want that to be as short as possible (but not empty).

The purpose of the default rule is to do something when there is no match for any of the tokens in the input language. When lex is used for tokenizing a language, such a situation is almost always erroneous because it means that the input begins with a character which is not the start of any valid token of the language.

Thus, a "catch any character" rule is coded as a form of error recovery. The idea is to discard the bad character (just one) and try tokenizing from the character after that one. This is only a guess, but it's a good guess because it's based on what is known: namely that there is one bad character in the input.

The recovery rule can be wrong. For instance suppose that no token of the language begins with `@`, and the programmer wanted to write the string literal `"@abc"`. Only, she forgot the opening `"` and wrote `@abc"`. The right fix is to insert the missing `"`, not to discard the `@`. But that would require a much more clever set of rules in the lexer.

Anyway, usually when discarding a bad character, you want to issue an error message for this case like "skipping invalid character '~` in line 42, column 3".

The default rule/action of copying the unmatched character to standard output is useful when lex is used for text filtering.  The default rule then brings about the semantics of a regex search (as opposed to a regex match): the idea is to search the input for matches of the lexer's token-recognizing state machine, while printing all material that is skipped by that search.

So for instance, a lex specification containing just the rule:

```
 "foo" { printf("bar"); }
```

will implement the equivalent of

```
 sed -e 's/foo/bar/g'
```

Answer (score 1):

Why does adding "." not do the trick? You can't perform an action in the absence of a matched amount. flex won't do anything if there is no match, so to add a "default" rule, just make it match something.

Comment: @barfuin You're commenting on an 11 year old answer, so you might as well be talking to another person. I do agree; feel free to edit it out.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem manually instead if trying to match the complement of a rule. This works fine because the matching pattern involved in this case is quite simple.

Comment: What is the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<*>.|\n   /* default action here */
```

Using this at the end of the file catches the default rule across all start spaces.  It's useful to find out where there may be holes.

What I don't know (and would like to know) is how to get flex to report where the default rule match has been found.