# Flex: unrecognized rule `(?s:.)`

Tags: regex, tokenize, flex-lexer, lex

In my flex program, I am unable to use any of these regex. Usage of any of them are generating `unrecognized rule` error.

```
%{
#include<stdio.h>
%}

%option nodefault
%option noyywrap
%option outfile="scanner.c"

%%

(?i:a) printf("rule1");

(?s:.) printf("rule2");

(?x:a b) printf("rule3");

(?#foo) printf("rule4");

[a-z]{-}[aeiou] printf("rule5");

%%
```

All of these are well defined in [this](https://www.cs.virginia.edu/%7Ecr4bd/flex-manual/Patterns.html) docs. I am confused, whether I am using wrong variant of flex! I am using windows machine with `GnuWin32 flex v2.5.4`.

This is the error being generated:

```
$flex misc/test_lexer.l
"misc/test_lexer.l", line 11: unrecognized rule
"misc/test_lexer.l", line 11: unrecognized rule
"misc/test_lexer.l", line 11: unrecognized rule
"misc/test_lexer.l", line 11: unrecognized rule
"misc/test_lexer.l", line 11: unrecognized rule
"misc/test_lexer.l", line 11: unrecognized rule
"misc/test_lexer.l", line 13: unrecognized rule
"misc/test_lexer.l", line 13: unrecognized rule
"misc/test_lexer.l", line 13: unrecognized rule
"misc/test_lexer.l", line 13: unrecognized rule
"misc/test_lexer.l", line 13: unrecognized rule
"misc/test_lexer.l", line 13: unrecognized rule
"misc/test_lexer.l", line 15: unrecognized rule
"misc/test_lexer.l", line 15: unrecognized rule
"misc/test_lexer.l", line 15: unrecognized rule
"misc/test_lexer.l", line 15: unrecognized rule
"misc/test_lexer.l", line 15: unrecognized rule
"misc/test_lexer.l", line 17: unrecognized rule
"misc/test_lexer.l", line 17: unrecognized rule
"misc/test_lexer.l", line 17: unrecognized rule
"misc/test_lexer.l", line 17: unrecognized rule
"misc/test_lexer.l", line 17: unrecognized rule
"misc/test_lexer.l", line 17: unrecognized rule
"misc/test_lexer.l", line 17: unrecognized rule
"misc/test_lexer.l", line 19: unrecognized rule
"misc/test_lexer.l", line 19: unrecognized rule
"misc/test_lexer.l", line 19: unrecognized rule
"misc/test_lexer.l", line 19: unrecognized rule
"misc/test_lexer.l", line 19: unrecognized rule
"misc/test_lexer.l", line 19: unrecognized rule
"misc/test_lexer.l", line 19: unrecognized rule
"misc/test_lexer.l", line 19: unrecognized rule
"misc/test_lexer.l", line 19: unrecognized rule
"misc/test_lexer.l", line 19: unrecognized rule
```

Comment: Please show the actual source file you tested, reduced to a [mre].

Comment: @rici done! check :)

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10267307/12357035) question mentions about the 5th rule mentioned here. But that part of the question in unattended in any of the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your flex installation if you want to use those constructs.

Flex 2.5.4, which was released more than 25 years ago, does not implement `{-}` nor does it implement any of the `(?:...)` syntaxes.

The manual you cite, which is also not the current version, specifies:

> This edition of The flex Manual documents flex version 2.6.3. It was last updated on 13 January 2017.

Flex v2.5.4 did implement the `/` trailing context operator, which was in the original version of this question. But note that `/` cannot be used inside parentheses, and since flex normally adds parentheses around macro expansions, `/` cannot be used in a macro expansion either.

Comment: After googling, I got these two links: https://sourceforge.net/projects/flex/ and https://sourceforge.net/projects/winflexbison/  Are there any other official sources for downloading?

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB: Flex started moving from SourceForge to GitHub about four years ago; the current repository is https://github.com/westes/flex/ . I don't know if winflexbison is really "official" --afaik, the flex authors don't release binaries-- but I think lots of people use it.

Comment: Hey, I have no idea how to run westes flex. It doesn't have a `bin` folder to add to path. Can you help me out.

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB: I haven't got a clue how to build that on Windows, and I haven't got a Windows machine so I'm not going to learn, either :-). As I said, the official version doesn't include an executable. It's really easy to build on any Unix-like system, and there are full instructions in the README; if you have all the build dependencies, it's just three commands. If you want a prebuilt binary, you probably want win_flex_bison3 from the winflexbison repository.